# A function to split a rectangle into $y$ squares (dimensions of these squares : $x$ per $x$)

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

How to define a function that splits a rectangle into $y$ squares (dimensions of these squares: $x$ per $x$) when knowning rectangle's width & height?

$x$ is unknown, $y$ can be known if you have $x$.

Comment: People who downvote because the question could be asked the wrong way. We're not all math genius. If you downvote, at least explain why...

Comment: Is x or y fixed? Or are you trying to find the largest squares which can fit into the rectangle?

Comment: Are x,y,width,height all integers? rational numbers? real numbers? It's hard to tell what the question is really asking, and that's why there's downvotes. If you can clear up the question so that we know what you're really asking and why you're having trouble with it, then we can possibly help you.

Comment: They are all integers. I want to split a rectangle in y squares. These squares' width and height is x.  (I use this in a code, they are variables, so technically the rectangle's dimensions are 'known' values). I have trouble with it because... Well I have know idea how to find this function. Like 0 ideas

Comment: If you want to alert a person to a comment you made, you must use the notation @username otherwise they won't know about it. Anyway, it is still unclear to me if y is a fixed number or x is a fixed number or neither.

Comment: @jens x is unknown, y can be known if you have x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rectangle with integer height $h$ and integer width $w$ can be split into squares of integer side length $x$ if $x$ divides both $h$ and $w$. So we can always have $x=1$. I presume though, that you are looking for the largest possible side length. That side length would be the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $h$ and $w$.

Comment: Totally what I was searching for ! But I got drawn by all the calculations on the page ha ha

Comment: Glad to help. :-)